# Static hostname not changing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hostname

I upgraded to 20.04 from 18.04. My hostname had an underscore (`My_PC`). Now, in my terminal, it says `sudo: unable to resolve host MyPC: Name or service not known`.

I tried:

`hostnamectl set-hostname My_PC`

That did not work.

`My_PC` is in my /etc/hosts file, **NOT** `MyPC`.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost My_PC
```

`cat /etc/hostname` shows:
`My_PC`

```
me@MyPC:~$ hostnamectl
  Static hostname: MyPC <--- WHY??????
  Pretty hostname: My_PC
  Icon name: computer-laptop
  Chassis: laptop
```

I did not get this error in my terminal until I upgraded. What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

`_` is an illegal character in hostname. Please see this [link](https://kb.iu.edu/d/afqs)
I am not sure why 18.04 did not reject it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try this in production environments or on systems without easy physical access.

In case you are fine with potentially breaking stuff at a random point in the future this is how I did it in a container (22.04 guest):
(see below for a slightly simpler method that only works outside of containers)

- write a small C program to call the `sethostname()` system call wrapper:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
    char hostname[] = "hostname_with_underscores";
    sethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname));
}
```

- compile it: `gcc -Wall -Wextra fix_hostname.c -o fix_hostname`
- try if it works: `sudo ./fix_hostname`. You should see the newly set hostnames in newly opened terminals or newly executed shells. If it does not work: Don't continue, this will only break stuff.
- if it does work: copy the program to e.g. /usr/sbin/fix_hostname
- write a service to run the program on system startup to e.g. /etc/systemd/system/fix_hostname.service:
  (derived from "/etc/rc.local Compatibility" unit file. See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html for unit file documentation in general.)

```
[Unit]
Description=run fix_hostname on startup
After=networkd-dispatcher.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fix_hostname

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

- enable the service: `sudo systemctl enable fix_hostname`
- disable anything hostname related (seemed to be needed on my system): `systemctl disable systemd-hostnamed.service; systemctl disable dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service`
- Reboot. Hopefully it works.

---

If your system is not inside a container it should be possible to use the following shellscript named e.g. fix_hostname instead of compiling a C program:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "hostname_with_underscores" > /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
```

Don't forget to make it executable (`chmod +x fix_hostaname`) and copy it to e.g. /usr/sbin/fix_hostname if it works; continue with the above instructions.